# Android: Uncaught TypeError: Object function Array() { [native code] } has no method 'from'

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview, jsfiddle

My `WebView` using a html file and a button calling `getTopRow()` javascript method from the html file. The method working on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efgpx4o9/1/) but android studio throwing follow error:

> 04-03 22:23:39.437 28260-28260/com.site.project E/Web Console: Uncaught TypeError: Object function Array() { [native code] } has no method 'from' at file:///android_asset/zbe/zbe.html:9

**JavaScript Method:**

```
function getTopRow(){
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("p");
    var obj = null;
    window.onscroll = function() {
        if (obj != null) {
          obj.style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
        var top = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        Array.from(elements).forEach(function(o) {
        var t = o.getBoundingClientRect(o).top;
        if (t > 0.0 && top > t) {
          obj = o;
          top = t;
        }
        });
        if (obj != null) {
            obj.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imported Array.from to html file and solved problem.

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 6, 22.1.2.1
// Reference: https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.from
if (!Array.from) {
  Array.from = (function () {
    var toStr = Object.prototype.toString;
    var isCallable = function (fn) {
      return typeof fn === 'function' || toStr.call(fn) === '[object Function]';
    };
    var toInteger = function (value) {
      var number = Number(value);
      if (isNaN(number)) { return 0; }
      if (number === 0 || !isFinite(number)) { return number; }
      return (number > 0 ? 1 : -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(number));
    };
    var maxSafeInteger = Math.pow(2, 53) - 1;
    var toLength = function (value) {
      var len = toInteger(value);
      return Math.min(Math.max(len, 0), maxSafeInteger);
    };
    // The length property of the from method is 1.
    return function from(arrayLike/*, mapFn, thisArg */) {
      // 1. Let C be the this value.
      var C = this;
      // 2. Let items be ToObject(arrayLike).
      var items = Object(arrayLike);
      // 3. ReturnIfAbrupt(items).
      if (arrayLike == null) {
        throw new TypeError("Array.from requires an array-like object - not null or undefined");
      }
      // 4. If mapfn is undefined, then let mapping be false.
      var mapFn = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : void undefined;
      var T;
      if (typeof mapFn !== 'undefined') {
        // 5. else
        // 5. a If IsCallable(mapfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
        if (!isCallable(mapFn)) {
          throw new TypeError('Array.from: when provided, the second argument must be a function');
        }
        // 5. b. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
        if (arguments.length > 2) {
          T = arguments[2];
        }
      }
      // 10. Let lenValue be Get(items, "length").
      // 11. Let len be ToLength(lenValue).
      var len = toLength(items.length);
      // 13. If IsConstructor(C) is true, then
      // 13. a. Let A be the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method of C with an argument list containing the single item len.
      // 14. a. Else, Let A be ArrayCreate(len).
      var A = isCallable(C) ? Object(new C(len)) : new Array(len);
      // 16. Let k be 0.
      var k = 0;
      // 17. Repeat, while k < len… (also steps a - h)
      var kValue;
      while (k < len) {
        kValue = items[k];
        if (mapFn) {
          A[k] = typeof T === 'undefined' ? mapFn(kValue, k) : mapFn.call(T, kValue, k);
        } else {
          A[k] = kValue;
        }
        k += 1;
      }
      // 18. Let putStatus be Put(A, "length", len, true).
      A.length = len;
      // 20. Return A.
      return A;
    };
  }());
}
```